# LibreOffice does not find libicui18n.60.so after upgrade 18.04->20.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 20.04, libreoffice

I have upgraded from bionic to fossa, and now LibreOffice complains that it does not find a shared library:

```
$ soffice 
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have purged and re-installed libreoffice, but that did not help.

What is strange is that if I look up the depencies

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin | grep icu
        libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007fe402c28000)
        libicui18n.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66 (0x00007fe402370000)
        libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 (0x00007fe401620000)
        libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007fe3fed7f000)
        libicui18n.so.60 => not found
        libicuuc.so.60 => not found
```

then I find dependencies on both version 60 and 66 of libicui18n and icuuc.

Comment: It seems that you have some local libraries installed. Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin | grep local` to the question.

Comment: I had old boost libraries compiled locally, which was the problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comment above, I had old boost libraries compiled locally, which was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To add libicui18n.so.60 to Ubuntu 20. You can add

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
```

to

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu60
```