# error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.66 ,libicudata.so.66 and libicui18n.so.66 upgraded

Tags: 22.04

I have application which is running in 20.04 and now in latest ubuntu it is throughing error not found those three libraries which are mentioned in title. Now in latest ubuntu i see it is upgraded to libicudata.so.70 ,libicudata.so.70 and libicui18n.so.70.

Can i know how my application can get older once
i tried following command
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libicu66

but not working
in conslole i am seeing follwoing message

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libicu66

Can any one have idea on this how i can resolve the issue

Comment: Accordin to online pakages search the Package is now named libicu70 in jammy https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libicu70

Comment: Then what about backward compatibility

Answer (score 5):

I had that same problem with another program and I was able to resolve it by adapting the solution found in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260310/libreoffice-does-not-find-libicui18n-60-so-after-upgrade-18-04-20-04).

First open the sources list:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add the Ubuntu 20 packages as a source by copying the following text to that file:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

Then update and install the desired package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu66
```

Hope this helps!